# How to use a function written on a cell as function syntax (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

So i have asked a similar question several days ago but i got no satisfying answer.

I want to ask about using a function that is written on a cell that is user defined, for example:

```
log(x)+2x+exp(x)
```

that is written on cell A1.

So how to use this string as a function syntax in VBA editor?

Comment: @R3uK Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `x` with some value then use `Application.Evaluate`

```
Function EvaluateEquation(equation As String, variable As String, value As Double)
    EvaluateEquation = Application.Evaluate _
       (Replace(equation, variable, value))
End Function
```

**Test and usage**

Let's say you have entered the equation `x^2+2` in sheet1, Cell `A1`. You can evaluate it for `x=2` this way:

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim result As Double
    result = EvaluateEquation(Sheet1.Range("A1").Text, "x", 2)
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

Output: 6

p.s.: since `x` is a letter that can appear inside the equation at any place (not only at the formal parameter), we should use a different (rare) combination for the formal parameter, such as `xxx`..

Comment: But how to use it as an integrand?

Comment: just like you would integrate any function numerically. Decide your step, increment x step by step, calculate f(x) at each step and multiply by the step and sum.

Comment: No, i mean about using that string as a function so that we can insert it as a function syntax

Comment: Could you provide an example with code, of how you inted to use it?

Comment: for example i have 
log(x)+2x+exp(x)
in A1

can i make it as the 
function f(x) : f="cell A1" : end function, just like VBA user defined function but it use a function on a cell

Comment: With my answer you can write a formula, say in `B1`, as `=EvaluateEquation(A1, "x", 2)`. But we need to use something else than `x` as a formal paramater, because now I realize that `x` can appear in `exp` and such. Maybe you should use something like `xxx` for example.

Comment: no, well ok that "evaluate equation" is good but i need more than that. I need it to do an iteration on it. which means that i need to make it as a user defined function as in vba function syntax

Comment: `for t = 1 to 100 sum = sum + EvaluateEquation(myEquation, "x", t)`. But again, use a different formal parameter, such as `xxx`, in both the equation and the caller.

Comment: That's the ultimate thing you can do with it, as far as I can see. You cannot *really transform it* into a VBA function, unless you add code dynamicaly to the VB project, and that's not recommended.

Comment: OK
Thank you for your response m8 :)